# Flex causes browser unresponsive when processing large amount of data

Tags: apache-flex, browser, flex3, flex4, flash

I have an actionscript function which is supposed to launch a panel and then fill in Networktopology data inside it.
As, network data is too large that it consumes much time and makes browser hang!!
Even I tried to display busy cursor which also stopped spinning when data was being processed.

How would I avoid this situation. How can I ensure processing large amount of data does not hang the browser.

Comment: As per one scenario, I need to draw 12000 links in a network topology. In order to compute start and end points of links, much time is taken by IBM ilog elixir graph component while I try to load it inside a panel model popup.

Comment: from the look of the questions , it seems , it is a NMS or EMS software..

Answer (score 2):

You can try to limit amount of processing per frame to say, 50 ms. When time limit is over, save state and return from ENTER_FRAME handlers. On next frame, if there is still unprocessed data, continue processing.
It can be tough task to split your algorithms, but until there is multithreading in Flash, this is the only way.
**edit:** some illustration of what I mean:
When you got data to process, call processData().

```
private static const TIME_LIMIT_MS:int = 50;
private function processData(event:Event = null):void {
    var time:int = getTimer();
    var currentTime:int;
    do {
    ...
    currentTime = getTimer();
    while (currentTime - time < TIME_LIMIT_MS)
    if (stillHaveWork)
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, processData);
    else
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, processData);
}
```

Some work also needed to make sure data is queued when there's still left work and new portion arrives.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample piece of code, it will be helpful even a pseudo code.

Comment: This only helps if you do the work in your code and can split it. If your bottleneck is external component, it will be not so easy. Is this graph component open source? If so, there's chance to split work inside it (although this may be complex task.)

Comment: It is not open source. We have purchased that.

Comment: If you really need so many nodes, I'm afraid you have to compute them yourself in little portions. Or decompile that component...

Comment: I hope you should be able to append the Topology data to the existing topology. If you can, then try to append the dataprovider in small data chunks(using Green Threading approach OR using the above code sample) until you are done. That way you won't get this freezing effect. I know as we did it for parsing a big XML for such a huge Network topology in my previous job. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what you mean by "Network Topology Data", you could give more info about that.  I'm getting the feeling that you're getting a very large XML back and you're trying to parse.  This is an issue as XML is very hard to parse properly, you should look into an alternative like AMF which is binary format which is very efficient.  You should also look into how you're parsing the data as any functions or loops that are going to be called a lot needs to be as fast as possible.  Also, *never* just store the XML and bind to that XML; parse the xml into your own model structure.

With that said, you can look into [Green Threading](http://jessewarden.com/2009/02/parsing-rendering-lots-of-data-in-flash-player.html) which is a way to fake multithreading without stopping the UI completely since Flex is single threaded.  You might want to post the offending code that's stopping your UI.  What you're doing isn't impossible, just need to do it properly :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am actually getting amf data in terms of VOs from Java backend. There is no XML parsing, it is done at server side. As we are using IBM ilog elixir component to display the full network topology with Nodes, links and subnets, I have to process all data at once. I will take a look at Green Threading.

Comment: oh, so it's more about drawing than anything else.  In that case, I wouldn't use ilog elixir component as those are made for general use and are probably not optimized for your kind of situation.  If I were you, I'd create my own component and take advantage of [Double Buffering and Blitting](http://jessewarden.com/2005/11/blitting-double-buffering-for-tile-based-games-in-flash-flex-part-1-of-3.html).  but really, 12000 "links"?  Does that need to be displayed all at the same time?  seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I know, but I cant help it. The usecase is upper boundary condition.

Comment: Even so, what you're trying to do is not impossible.  Make sure to cache the bitmap (as I'm fairly sure it doesn't need to animate all the time) and use those concepts I was telling you about.  You might even be able to create those 12000 links as long as your algorithm is really fast.  You could also easily do green threading for this just in case the user has a slower computer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Flash is not multi threaded in every way and runs within the flash player plugin it highly depends on the clients performance.

1. Take as much calculation to the server as you can.
2. Prevent custom ItemRenderers for large data grids.
3. Load data which is actually visible on the screen and reload if somebody changes the view like in a page browser

Comment: Your suggestions are helpful. But I need to process data to load a full network topology which is large and complex. Time is consumed by the linking of Nodes and subnets within topology.

Comment: Of how many nodes do we speak and how you deliver them. Do you use the spring graph component ?

Comment: We use IBM iLog Elixir enterprise Diagram component.